# Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and app-private files

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I am working on getting my application over to scoped storage. One feature of the app is that it contains document templates stored as application assets. At run time, they are copied to local storage, here: (code is Java)

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                              Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                              .getAbsolutePath() +
                              File.separator + "Templates";
```

Since these files are private to the app, I am happy to put them in

```
String path = context.getFilesDir()
            .getAbsolutePath() +
             File.separator + "Templates";
```

But I'm also planning to do this (or something like it) for the user to browse for files:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
newIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
newIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

My question is, how can I get ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to include as browsable the place where I've put my templates?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to expose private files from your app in the system file picker is to [create a custom `DocumentsProvider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider). This would add your app as a source of files that the user can pick from.

Note that with this approach, there is no requirement to copy files to local storage at all - your code for [opening a document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider#openDocument) can use `AssetManager`'s [`openFd()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetManager#openFd(kotlin.String)) method along with [`getParcelFileDescriptor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor#getParcelFileDescriptor()) to directly pass that through to the calling app without going through the `File` APIs at all.

Comment: However, AFAIK, the `DocumentsProvider` approach means that *every app on the device* that uses the Storage Access Framework will also see your app as a document provider. You can [use some tricks](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider#security) to say that your app's documents are only available from your app, but your app will still show up as an option. That may be a feature, or it may be a bug, depending on the scenario. If there is some trick to having an in-my-app-only `DocumentsProvider`, though, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yes, making your files available to users means they become something the user can always access. There's in fact, only the exact opposite API in [`EXTRA_EXCLUDE_SELF`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_EXCLUDE_SELF) to _remove_ your own document providers from your own calls to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, etc.

Comment: Is there a way using SAF to get a list of URIs in different places, and present my own picker? Right now I'm using File.listFiles() to populate my own file navigator.

Comment: The whole point of scoped storage and sand boxing each app's storage is that the user is explicitly involved in choosing what files (or folders, if you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) they give your app access to. You can certainly ask the user to go through the effort in manually selecting files and folders they deem relevant to your app and you can then show a list of all of those files in your app, but the recommendation has always been to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` as the 'File -> Open' equivalent. I.e., let the user pick exactly what they want directly.